# Ubuntu 14.04 WebBrowser.app does not see flash

Tags: 14.04, flash, browser, default-browser

The new WebBrowser.app now in Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit does not play flash.

I have Adobe flash installed and working both in Firefox and Chrome, but the Browser.app says it is not installed.

When I try to play flash I get the message that I need to install the latest 32bit flash, but I have a 64bit system and 64bot flash is installed..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webbrowser-app does not currently support flash. As far as webm (html5), support is limited to vp8 & vp9

Open this link in webbrowser-app to see current support -

http://html5test.com/

[Here's an example of a YouTube video it will play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFu5qXMuaJU)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it is still early days for this browser.

Answer (score 0):

Install 32-bit Flash to see if that helps, since that may be a 32-bit browser.

If it works in the other browsers, I don't understand why it's so important, unless it's OCD.

Comment: No not OCD, just a Browser offered by Ubuntu, I just hoped to use it. But I guess Flash is not supported yet. Thanks