# Flash Player does not install on Ubuntu Web Browser

Tags: flash, webbrowser-app

Flash player works fine with Chrome, but cannot install on Ubuntu Web Browser.

I am on Ubuntu 17.04 and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'can not install'? The normal install command would be

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

If that isn't what you are searching for then could you please provide more information about your problem? Also [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Adobe_Flash/) might be helpful. Regards, ADDB

Comment: Thanks, but already works fine with Chrome browser, but when I use Ubundu Web Browser for a chat window msg says install flash player

Comment: What do you mean with ubuntu web browser? Are you talking about firefox?

Comment: @user215500 Chrome has its own flash preinstalled, you need to run the command in the answer for system wide flash.

Comment: Please, please describe the problem more properly. What browser, what chat window, do you have something like screenshots? Anything?

Comment: The Macromedia Flash Player is required. Get the free player here (opens in a new window)

So this is the msg I get when I try to open a chat window in Ubuntu Web Browser

Comment: @Mark Kirby, I ran the commmand, and it says its already the newest version, I rebooted but still not working

Comment: @user215500 again, what kind of chat window is opening? I don't think any of us can do much with the amount of information we have right now

Comment: @ADDBhttp://mycc.silverdaddies.com/camchat/camchat.asp?profile=148898&code=67&server=silverdaddies.com

Comment: Turns out @Kemal according the this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/460303/ubuntu-14-04-webbrowser-app-does-not-see-flash flash is not supported buy the ubuntu browser, why not just use chrome or firefox? the ubuntu browser is just a very basic system web browser.

Comment: @MarkKirby, thanks I'll use Chrome for chat purposes, but ubuntu browser is fine and fast for general use